# Flash AS3 Remove parts of a movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm doing a pong game in AS3. However when the ball hit on my paddle i want to remove a part of it (the paddle).
My ball and my paddle are both movieclips.
How can i do it? What's the best way to remove, not the whole movieclip but just a part of it.

Here is my code:

```
import flash.events.Event;


var ballSpeedX:int = 4;
var ballSpeedY:int = 4;

init();

function init():void {
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
}

function loop(e:Event):void {

    playerPaddle.x = mouseX;

    if(playerPaddle.hitTestObject(ball)){
        if(ballSpeedY >= 0){
            ballSpeedY *= -1;
            ball.removeSelf();
        }
    }

    if(playerPaddle.y - playerPaddle.height/2 < 0){ 
        playerPaddle.y = playerPaddle.height/2;

    //check if bottom of paddle is below bottom of screen
    } else if(playerPaddle.y + playerPaddle.height/2 > stage.stageHeight){
        playerPaddle.y = stage.stageHeight - playerPaddle.height/2;
    }

    ball.x += ballSpeedX;
    ball.y += ballSpeedY;

    if(ball.x <= ball.width/2){ 
        ball.x = ball.width/2; 
        ballSpeedX *= -1;

    }else if(ball.x >= stage.stageWidth-ball.width/2){
        ball.x = stage.stageWidth-ball.width/2;
        ballSpeedX *= -1;

    }

    if(ball.y <= ball.height/2){ 
        ball.y = ball.height/2;
        ballSpeedY *= -1;

    } else if(ball.y >= stage.stageHeight-ball.height/2){
        ball.y = stage.stageHeight-ball.height/2;
        ballSpeedY *= -1;

    }
}
```

Comment: Is the ball movieclip inside another movieclip?

Comment: @nikel no, it's a simple movieclip.

Answer (score 0):

```
Graphics.beginFill(0,0)
```

is probably the best method.

It's like painting with rubber (the second param means *transparent*)

You can move around with `lineTo` / `curveTo` and then *commit* with `endFill`.